# Lua gfind issue

Tags: lua

> ```
>     testA = "test.test test.test"
>     local t1 = {}
>     for X in string.gfind (testA, "[^ ]+") do
>     table.insert (t1 ,X)
>     end
>     local first = table.concat(t1, "", 1, 1);
>
>     --output/first test.test
>
>     testA = "11.11.11.11 test.test"
>     local t2 = {}
>     for X in string.gfind (testA, "[^ ]+") do
>     table.insert (t2 ,X)
>     end
>     local first = table.concat(t2, "", 1, 1);
>
>     --output/first 11.11.11.11
>
>     testA = "100.100.100.100  test.test"
>     local t3 = {}
>     for X in string.gfind (testA, "[^ ]+") do
>     table.insert (t3 ,X)
>     end
>     local first = table.concat(t3, "", 1, 1);
>
>     --output/first 100.100.100.100    test.test
> ```

Does anyone know why the 3rd item wont split with gfind? , cant figure out why
it works for two strings but not the third.

Comment: [Your code works just fine in IdeaOne.](http://ideone.com/vved5) I changed the `table.concat` statements to print their results, and everything is as expected. So odds are your problem isn't in the code you've shown.

Comment: thanks, I pasted what you pasted and it worked, but I noticed your code had one less space, testA = "100.100.100.100<-4 spaces>test.test" with the extra space it fails

Comment: I copy and pasted it *directly* from your example. It's not my fault that your example isn't an example of the problem.

Comment: thanks for your time, appreciate it, what do you make of this http://ideone.com/poVYx ?

Comment: Update your question with that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that a tab character is not the same thing as a space. If you want to skip all whitespace characters, you need to actually skip whitespace characters, not just regular space:

```
string.gfind (testA, "[%S]+")
```